# What is equivalent code for @JoinColumn in hibernate xml

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the equivalent code for **@JoinColumn** in **hibernate xml**

Comment: Your question is very lacking in content. You need to provide some code example of what you are looking for. Maybe provide some information of what you have looked at so far and why its not what you need. This kind of question as it is now should be closed as it is not a complete question.